# Does the resulting image from using ImageIO.read() still use the same memory passed to it?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, bufferedimage, bytebuffer

I am working on an OpenGL project which requires me to implement the JVM through the JNI library to use JavaGraphics2D for rendering to an OpenGL mapped buffer in c++. I understand that I can create a `java.nio.ByteBuffer` object using a `void*` pointer pointing to mapped buffer:

```java
jobject NewDirectByteBuffer(JNIEnv* env, void* address, jlong capacity);
```

If I pass this `ByteBuffer` by converting it to a `byte[]` array, wrapping that array around a `ByteArrayInputStream` and using `ImageIO.read()` , in the end will that `BufferedImage` still be using the same memory as the `void*` pointer for storage or does the ImageIO method allocate new memory for the BufferedImage storage? i.e If I draw onto the BufferedImage using Java2DGraphics, will it result in the original void* memory being changed as well?

If that is not the case I will have to copy the BufferedImage data into the ByteBuffer

Answer (score 3):

ImageIO.read works off a variety of input source and allocates own memory, it doesn't share your original byte[] with the BufferedImage it returns.

So you will need to call ImageIO.write to get back the modifications.

Comment: Is there another class/Library I might be able to use that could do this?

Comment: I would doubt you'd find something - and also has issues if the storage is extended. Pretty much all image readers will read from some form of  `InputStream` as their source and have no knowledge of the underlying storage format which could be ByteBuffer, byte[], File/Path, ZIP / compressed, HTTP connection. It shouldn't be hard to get `ImageIO.write` to save to new `ByteArrayOutputStream` and you copy the buffers back.

Comment: @fsxflyer789Productions your original memory is already decoupled from the `byte[]` array you’ve created from it. Then, you wrapped the array in a `ByteArrayInputStream` whose read operations are copying the data into a target storage, in principle. Besides the impossibility of the resulting `BufferedImage`’s storage to be connected to your original memory, what do you actually expect when the image is modified? The data to be re-encoded in the original image format on every update? Image decoding is not necessarily a reversible process at all.

Comment: @Holger since the original memory buffer is connected to a Texture, any changes done to the Buffer in java to reflect changes in the original memory itself

Comment: @fsxflyer789Productions when you use `ImageIO`, it implies that the source is encoded in a particular image format, png, jpeg, gif, whatever. So you expect that whenever you change a single pixel in the `BufferedImage`, the entire image gets re-encoded to the source buffer? Besides the insane overhead of that idea, what if the new encoded picture doesn’t fit into the original buffer? The size of compressed data depends on the actual content.